# How to make strings not repeat in a random word generator

Tags: python, string, random, while-loop

I am making a random string generator, however I am having issues making the strings not repeat when generating

Here's the Code:

```
import random
import string

repeat = True

pp = input("What's your text? ").lower()
pl = len(pp)

while repeat == True:
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(pl))
    print(result_str)
    if result_str == pp:
        repeat = False
```

How can I make the strings always different from one another

I've tried searching it up on google, but got no result I was happy with.

Comment: You could store each randomly generated string in a list & only display a newly generated string if its is not contained in the list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below. In the below example, I suppose you want the length of each `string==10` and you want to generate 10 strings that don't have repeating. In each iteration, we generate a random string and if generated string doesn't exist in `seen` we add generate string to `seen` and increase one-time `cnt`. Until `cnt < count_not_repeated_string` we continue to generate random strings.

```
import random
import string


pl = 10
count_not_repeated_string = 10
cnt = 0
seen = set()

while cnt < count_not_repeated_string:
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(pl))
    if not result_str in seen:
        seen.add(result_str)
        cnt += 1
print(seen)
```

Output:

```
{'pmyolioqqh', 'lufictzhov', 'jifdiwvupa', 'eafmoxmiqx', 'ktdfmekwoa', 'vtpjtittgt', 'rvvfdreuox', 'crfgbveazn', 'jntmlfhixy', 'gkhxcfuydy'}
```